# Flutter dialog RTL

Tags: flutter

I did the following

```js
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      locale: Locale('he'),
      localizationsDelegates: [
        // ... app-specific localization delegate[s] here
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('he', ''), // Heberew
        const Locale('en', ''), // English
      ],
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      home: new Main(
          // Pass the appropriate camera to the TakePictureScreen widget.
          ),
    ),
  );
}

class Main extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainState createState() => _MainState();
}

class _MainState extends State<Main> {
  Widget _buildDialog(BuildContext context) {
    print("_buildDialog");
    return MaterialApp(
      // locale: Locale('he'),
      // localizationsDelegates: [
      //   // ... app-specific localization delegate[s] here
      //   GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      //   GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      //   GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      // ],
      // supportedLocales: [
      //   const Locale('he', ''), // Heberew
      //   const Locale('en', ''), // English
      // ],
      title: "Test",
      home: Scaffold(
        body: AlertDialog(
          content: Row(children: <Widget>[
            Text('1'),
            Text('2'),
          ]),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: const Text('CLOSE'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, false);
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: const Text('SHOW'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, true);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showPushDialog() {
    print("DIALOG");
    showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => _buildDialog(context),
    ).then((bool shouldNavigate) {
      if (shouldNavigate == true) {
        _navigateToPushDetail();
      }
    });
  }

  void _navigateToPushDetail() {
    print("TODO: Goto...");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      locale: Locale('he'),
      localizationsDelegates: [
        // ... app-specific localization delegate[s] here
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('he', ''), // Heberew
        const Locale('en', ''), // English
      ],
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: new Material(
          child: Row(children: <Widget>[
            Text('1'),
            Text('2'),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print("pushed?");
                _showPushDialog();
              },
              child: Text("press me"),
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When running the App it shows 21 in RTL, as expected.
but when clicking the button it display 12 (instead of 21 like in the parent page)

if I uncomment the lines in _buildDialog (37-47) the dialog will show in RTL, so this will solve my problem.

My questions are:

1.
Is there a better way to do this?

2.
Note that I also need to surround AlertDialog with MaterialApp and Scaffold, 
which is not clear why necessary?

3.
Why we need a new context?

4.
Why we need new localizations definition?

5.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MaterialApp` widget provides features like `Navigator`, `Theme`, `Directionality`, etc. It mostly used as root widget. You don't have to use it in every page.

`Scaffold` widget is useful to create new page. It offers features like `AppBar`, `Drawer`, `BottomNavigationBar`, etc. Since it tries to fill the device screen, don't wrap it around `AlertDialog`.

I have done some changes.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      locale: Locale('he'),
      localizationsDelegates: [
        // ... app-specific localization delegate[s] here
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('he', ''), // Heberew
        const Locale('en', ''), // English
      ],
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      home: new Main(
        // Pass the appropriate camera to the TakePictureScreen widget.
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class Main extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainState createState() => _MainState();
}

class _MainState extends State<Main> {
  Widget _buildDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      content: Row(children: <Widget>[
        Text('1'),
        Text('2'),
      ]),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: const Text('CLOSE'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context, false);
          },
        ),
        FlatButton(
          child: const Text('SHOW'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context, true);
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _showPushDialog() {
    print("DIALOG");
    showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => _buildDialog(context),
    ).then((bool shouldNavigate) {
      if (shouldNavigate == true) {
        _navigateToPushDetail();
      }
    });
  }

  void _navigateToPushDetail() {
    print("TODO: Goto...");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
      ),
      body: new Material(
        child: Row(children: <Widget>[
          Text('1'),
          Text('2'),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print("pushed?");
              _showPushDialog();
            },
            child: Text("press me"),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: 10x, Short answer is: `move your MaterialApp to main`, it works... but can you answer the `why` part? i.e. why moving `MaterialApp` to `main` solve the issue

Comment: That actually solved a few more similar issue in my App (regarding drawer), wander why? it seems that the important of this is not stressed up enough

Comment: Each widget gets its `Directionality` from its immediate `MaterialApp` ancestor. In your code, the `AlertDialog` gets it directionality from `MaterialApp` where you commented `// locale: Locale('he')`. So by default, its provides LTR directionality to its children

Comment: @EliaWeiss Note that, `MaterialApp` is most commonly used root widget. But  you can still use it anywhere and any number of times as you need.

Comment: originally I didn't have `MaterialApp`  in the `_buildDialog` and I still had the same issue (thats why I added `MaterialApp` there - I comment the lines only for the question), so it is still not answering my question, why  `MaterialApp` has to be in `main`?

Comment: I am not sure. Just now I copied your code and removed `MaterialApp` in `_buildDialog`. I didn't get the issue.

Comment: my original project is much more complicated, so I tried to minimize it here and might got confuse, but the bottom line is that I simply has to move the MaterialApp to main and the problem was solve (along with a few other issues) 10x